# What software and make charts, screen stocks, like in this answer?

Tags: software, chart

I looked at this question

[Why would I want a diversified portfolio, versus throwing my investments into an index fund?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22917/why-would-i-want-a-diversified-portfolio-versus-throwing-my-investments-into-an)

and I tried to find the software victor was talking about but I couldn't. I cant comment on the question so I wanted to ask what software does that look like?

Answer (score 3):

The charting software is called [Incredible Charts](http://www.incrediblecharts.com/), they have a free version with the data updated the next morning or various levels of payment versions with data 15 to 20 minutes delayed. I used to pay for the top version, about $250 per year as I used it for shorter term trading with CFDs. I am now trading stocks and warrants more medium to long term, so am using other software (see below) and don't put my orders in whilst the market is open, so I don't need the 20 minute delayed data anymore and just use the free data (as I already have all my indicators set up in the software).

The search box with the criteria to search for stocks and the quick test box are from a software called [VectorVest](http://www.vectorvest.com/), you can trial it out for 5 weeks for $10. If your happy with it you then pay $600 for the year for End of Day data or more for live data in the US. In Australia we only have the End of Day data for now (which I am happy with as it suits my trading). This program also has a charting program and a backtesting function to test your strategies. The search engine is really good, as you can use one or more of their many saved searches (using both fundamental and technical criteria) or you can create your own. They also provide some training on how to use it effectively. I could talk a lot more about it but if you are interested you can check the website out and maybe do the 5 week trial for $10.

I then just use a Snipping Tool program on my laptop to capture sections of my screen, save them and then post them online (but you probably already know about this one).

Comment: @Samuel - yes I like it. It suits my type of trading in trying to pick fundamentally healthy stocks whilst they are up-trending. I consider myself a trend follower so find that I can easily fit strategies using VectorVest into my trading plan. Another thing I like about them is how they advocate risk management (using stop losses), something I learnt about quite a while ago and think is one of the most important things to incorporate before you even attempt to invest or trade your hard earned money.